# Thread synchronization with EventHandler

Tags: c#, synchronization

I stuck with choosing synchronization primitive.

This is the case:
I have pool of threads, that are in infinitive loop, and waits for some event. And another thread that should invoke this event. When event fires all wating thread should make one iteration and fall back for waiting event again.

Should I use manualResetEvent for this? I can't understand, is there any garanty, that if i wrote in control thread something like this

```
event.Set();
event.Reset();
```

All waiting threads make iteration, and all waiting threads makes only one, not two ore three, iterations.

Or should I use another primitive for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Monitor.Wait(someObject)` in the looping threads, and `Monitor.PulseAll(someObject)` in the event raising thread.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've tried this, but i always get SynchronizationLockException when try to call Monitor.Wait. As far as i reed this becouse i need call Monitor.Enter(object) before call Monitor.Wait(object). In MSDN i've read this description of wait method: Releases the lock on an object and blocks the current thread until it reacquires the lock. So only one thread from my pool will work simultaneously, becouse they will need lock someObject for resume. Isn't it?

Comment: You need some lock statements in there around your Monitor calls: `lock (someObject) { Monitor.Wait(someObject); }` and `lock (someObject) { Monitor.PulseAll(someObject); }`.  When you do a `Monitor.Wait`, the context is exited and other objects can acquire the lock.

Comment: Read the Remarks section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateab679.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thank's a lot. This looks like a magic when i've tried this code first time. Now i think i understand. Threads one by one obtains exclusive lock, enter critical section, calls wait so relise lock and moves to waiting queue, then when i call PulseAll, thread moves to active queue, then one by one obtain exclusive lock and leave critical section. Very logic solution, when you can understand it. Thanks a lot for answer!